# Declaring relationships in sequelize?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I've got three models I am trying to define a relationship between them.

**Models:**
User
Payment
Debtor

- User has many Payments
- Payment belongs to User
- Payment has many Debtors
- Debtor belongs to Payment
- Debtor belongs to Payment

Do I need to define the relationship in the source and the target? i.e.

```
User.hasMany(Payment, {as: 'Payments'})
```

and also

```
Payment.belongsTo(User)
```

or can I get away with just defining it in one model?

I appear to get errors when trying to define it in both. The model I import is `undefined` and therefore when I try pass it into the "belongsTo()" or "hasMany()" functions I get the error `called with something that's not an instance of Sequelize.Model`

When I only include it in one model, it doesn't create the relationship correctly.

My models are as follows:

Payment model:

```
import { sequelize } from '../config';
import Sequelize from 'sequelize';
import User from './User';


const Payment = sequelize.define('payment', {
  amount: {
    type: Sequelize.FLOAT
  },
  reference: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING
  },
  user_id: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER
  }
});

Payment.belongsTo(User)


export default Payment;
```

User model:

```
import { sequelize } from '../config';
import Sequelize from 'sequelize';
import Payment from './Payment';

const User = sequelize.define('user', {
  email: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING
  },
  username: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING
  },
  firstName: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING
  },
  lastName: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING
  },
  facebookID: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING
  }
});

User.hasMany(Payment, {as: 'Payments'})

export default User;
```

// EDIT

When I try create a new user with a payment, I get the error `payment is not associated to user!`

```
exports.create = (req, res) => {

    User.create({
      email: 'test3@gmail.com',
        firstName: "Test",
        lastName: "Test",
        username: 'fnord',
      payment: [
        { amount: 10.00},
      ]
    }, {
      include: [ Payment ]
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens because in `payment` you require `User` model and vice-versa, in `user` you require `Payment` (circular dependency). In order to avoid this situation you would have to declare both models in the same file or you could follow the Sequelize recommended way

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {

    return sequelize.define('modelName', {
        // attributes
    }, {
        // additional options, like classMethods in which you could create the association
        classMethods: {
            associate: function(models) {
                this.belongsTo(models.Model);
                this.hasMany(models.Model);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

In order to achieve it you would have to use the [`sequelize-cli`](https://github.com/sequelize/cli) module. If you install it, you could use `sequelize init` command which would generate a file which registers all models to the sequelize (all those models are initially in one location, however you can change it by modifying the auto generated file).

In this case, sequelize iterates over every model, registers it (with use of [`sequelize.import()`](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/sequelize/#importpath-model) method) and calls the `associate` function which creates relations between models. This way would prevent the situation you have mentioned.

Comment: I am still getting "payment is not associated to user!". I have tried using the sequelize-cli and initiating the project. But is sequelize-cli really required? I don't really want all the extra stuff that comes with it i.e. seeders and migrations etc.

Comment: Where do you get this `payment is not associated to user` error? Could you edit the question with part of code that causes it? If it comes to `sequelize-cli` of course it is not required - you can go on without it - but keep in mind the circular dependencies. What is more, you will need migrations later when making changes to database tables.

Comment: have added the code which causes the error. I am trying to create a new user with payment but I believe there is no relationship set so it wont let me.

Comment: Finnally got it working! Thanks for your suggestion using sequelize-cli. It's actually exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

if Someone is struggling with Sequelize associations like me, this might help for you as this is not mentioned any where in documentation that how you can make associations if you are using `Sequelize.define` i was also facing an issue and made this work for me

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const User = sequelize.define('User', {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.BIGINT,
      primaryKey: true,
    },
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING
    },
    email: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      unique : true,
    },
    password: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING
    },
      status: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING
     },
     });
     let Bookmark = sequelize.model('Bookmark');
     User.hasMany(Bookmark,{foreignKey : 'user_id', as 'bookmarks'});
     return User;
  };
```

hope it works!